# Is there a spreadsheet version of .rtf?

Tags: microsoft-excel, compatibility, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, file-format

For a text document, there's multiple format options: .doc, .docx, .odt, .rtf, etc.  I use .rtf for all text documents, because its compatible with nearly everything.  My question is, is there a format for spreadsheets that's equally compatible?

Comment: Perhaps `.csv`?

Comment: Depends if you want to use macros/vba or not ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.

- [Comma separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (.CSV) are just text files.  Every spreadsheet program is able to open and import them.
- Microsoft's .XLS format *is* rather universal.  Most major spreadsheet programs can open .XLS as well.
- .ODS is the open format spreadsheet.  Most modern spreadsheet programs can open it, however most people wouldnt know what it is called, but rely on the icon to recognize it.  Is it universal?  Probably, universally known?  Not really.

Comment: Microsoft's XLSX format, the XML format used by recent Excel versions, is also an open specification.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities:

- [`.slk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYmbolic_LinK_(SYLK)), like `.rtf`, was created by Microsoft for exchanging data.  However unlike `.rtf`, there is no published specification and it cannot handle Unicode.
- [`.dif`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format) does have a published specification.  Like `.slk`, it cannot handle Unicode.
- `.csv` files are compatible with basically everything.  However unlike `.rtf`, they only store data, not formatting.
- `.xls` is outdated but still widely used for compatibility.  Unlike `.rtf` and the other formats in this list, these files cannot be opened with a text editor.
- `.xlsx` and `.ods` each work best in their preferred Office suite, but they can be used with most spreadsheet software.  They can also be viewed with a text editor after unzipping.

My suggestion would be `.xlsx` if you have Microsoft Excel or `.ods` if you do not.